Question about Munkres Elements of AT: Lemma 3.2 (exercise 3.3)
Lemma 3.2. Let $L$ be a complex; Let $f$ be a labelling of its vertices; let $g:|L|\to|K|$ be the associated pasting map. Let $L_0$ be a full subcomplex of $L$. Suppose that whenever $v$ and $w$ are vertices of $L$ having the same label:
$(1)\,v$  and $w$ belong to $L_0$.
$(2)\, \overline {St (v)} $ and $\overline {St(w)}$ are disjoint.
Then $dim(g(\sigma))=dim(\sigma)$ for all $\sigma \in L$. Furthermore, if $g(\sigma_1)=g(\sigma_2)$, then $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ must be disjoint simplices belonging to $L_0$.
Munkres claims, "The proof is easy." First, I would like to understand what the lemma says. Munkres defines dimension of a simplex to be the number of vertices minus 1. I have no idea how to prove $dim(g(\sigma))=dim(\sigma)$ using the "given" part of the lemma. Am I to prove the number of vertices in the two simplices $g(\sigma)$ and $\sigma$ are equal? How? Since vertices with the same lable map to the same image, the number will not be the same. I am sure I am completely missing the point of all this. Thanks in advance for clarification.
I can't find a good reference or tutorial on "simplicial maps" and their "obvious properties". I am self-studying and I would really love a primer rather than a book like "Piecewise Linear Topology". I need basic definitions and examples of manipulations.
I don't know if a reference figure is needed. I can't paste one, so...
Here is an exemplary vertex figure from Munkres from the page on which the Lemma appears
